# Jetpack compose what is the best way to save mutablelist of custom object inside device?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

Inside my @Composable function i have mutableStateList where i perform adding and deleting entries which are displayed inside LazyColumn. Is there any way to store that mutableStateList inside device so it won't reset after closing application?

```
@Composable
fun TodoAppContent() {
val todos = remember { (DataProvider.listOfToDoEntries.toMutableStateList()) }
//more code...
}

data class ToDo(
val title: String,
val description: String))


object DataProvider {
val listOfToDoEntries = listOf(
    ToDo(title = "Take out garbage", description = ""),
    ToDo(title = "Walk dog", description = ""))}
```

Comment: non-related to compose, but you need to have a local database like Room for example instead of static data provider

Comment: @tamtom's right that the kind of data you're storing fits a database, but the general approach to storing custom objects is serialisation, something like Kotlin's `serialization` component: https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization/blob/master/docs/serialization-guide.md You basically convert your data to a string (usually) and then you can store that in something like `SharedPreferences`, and fetch it and deserialise it to get your data back. Sometimes you don't need a full-on database, or you just want to test a thing before going all in (a database is probably in your future though!)